# How to fix this mouse hover transform scale effect (animation provided)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a GridView with images, so if I mouse over up, it displays the image correctly, however if I go down, it won't. I believe the problem is there's an overlay caused by CSS but I'm not sure how to get around it.

[image]

Here's my css code:

```
.enlarge:hover {
    transform:scale(5);
    transform-origin:20% 20%;
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:ImageField ItemStyle-CssClass="enlarge" DataImageUrlField="FileName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ControlStyle-Height="20px" HeaderText="Swatch">
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
</asp:ImageField>
```

Animation credit: http://www.screentogif.com (great tool to screen capture to gif - no affiliation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this CSS needed to add `img`:

```
.enlarge:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(15);
    -moz-transform: scale(15);
    -o-transform: scale(15);
    transform: scale(15);
    transform-origin: -15% 50%;
}
```